# I want to start a task periodically after every 1 second no matter whether previous task ends on not

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to run a task periodically after every 1 second no matter whether previous task ends on not. I tried below code but it is not working it waiting 
for previous task to finish then start the another task.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     ScheduledExecutorService scheduledPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
     scheduledPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
                 public void run(){
                     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "startTime : "+ new Date());
                    sleepForNSeconds(5);
                     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()  +"endTime : "+ new Date());
                 }
                 }, 0,1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }
```

Output:

```
pool-1-thread-1startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:04:15 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-1endTime : Wed Jul 06 21:04:21 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-1startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:04:21 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-1endTime : Wed Jul 06 21:04:26 IST 2016
pool-1-thread-2startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:04:26 IST 2016
```

Please suggest which api i should use to achieve this. I want startTime should be printed every 1 second no matter whether it finished or not.

If coreSize is 5 then how many new thread ScheduledExecutorService can create if required when 5 threads are already working?

**Note:** I also tried scheduleAtFixedRate api of Timer class but that too does not solve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my approach. Please suggest if there is some better apporach.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     while(true){
         sleepForNSeconds(1);
         new Thread(new Test().new Mytask()).start();
     }

 }  

 class Mytask implements Runnable {

     public void run() {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                 + " startTime : " + new Date());
         sleepForNSeconds(5);
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " endTime : "
                 + new Date());
     }
 }
```

Output:

```
Thread-0 startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:47 IST 2016
Thread-1 startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:48 IST 2016
Thread-2 startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:49 IST 2016
Thread-3 startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:50 IST 2016
Thread-4 startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:51 IST 2016
Thread-0 endTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:53 IST 2016
Thread-5 startTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:53 IST 2016
Thread-1 endTime : Wed Jul 06 21:41:54 IST 2016
```

Comment: Creating and destroying threads is expensive.  It's far better to re-use threads by using a _thread pool_ (e.g., `ThreadPoolExecutor`).  If you want to fire off one task every second, and if each task takes N seconds on average to perform, then you'll want to have at least N threads in the pool.

Comment: yes you are right but  In my case i am unaware of howmuch time the task will take it might take 1sec to 15 min. Is it advisable to keep core size 15*60 in this case ?

Comment: 900 threads is a lot.  What are those tasks going to do that must be started precisely once every second, that can't be aborted and, is so enormously variable in how long they take to complete?

Comment: They are performing some cassandra db ops (read/write). and the latency depends on loaded  on db ( or some other reason) sometime if db is loaded the latency is high. If i run that thread every 60 sec and the time of taks is max 15 min (Although till now i have observed 5 min latency but i am playing safe) then is this ok to keep  core size 15 ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method isn't good idea, couse as [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) say:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

You can always use `schedule()` method and invoke itself at the beginning, should work too:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    scheduledPool.schedule(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            scheduledPool.schedule(this,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "startTime : "+ new Date());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()  +"endTime : "+ new Date());
        }
    },1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this does not work as expected if sleep time is 10 sec and core size is 5. In my case i am unaware of how much time the task will take it might take 1sec to 15 min.